# python's zip function with compression and operating systems

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, flask

I currently have a flask app which uses `send_from_directory()` to send a zip file. The zip file is constructed by a simple python script, which is structured very much around the example in Python Phrasebook.

```
import zipfile
import os

tFile = zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
files = os.listdir('/some/directory/somewhere')
for f in files:
  tFile.write(f)
for f in tFile.namelist():
  print "compressed %s" % f
tFile.close()
```

and in my flask app, almost identical to the example they used to send from directory:

```
@app.route('/path/to/route/tFile.zip')
def send_zip:
  return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.zip)
```

when I try to get the file on mac, it works perfectly fine and extracts correctly. However, when I use windows (with the default unzipping program), the files will not extract. Is there any reason that this would happen?

Comment: what's the error you get? iirc the special character list is slightly different for mac vs. windows, so there are some filenames that are valid on mac, not valid on pc and vice-versa.

Comment: when trying to open it on windows, it simply says that it cannot open the archive. This is true of the window default as well as 7zip

Comment: What do your filenames look like? Are you trying to zip things from subdirectories with `/` characters or something weird like that which Windows does not support?